# getting notice is undefined variable $con and warning mysqli_query expect parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, xampp

I am  getting error that `$con is undefined` and  `mysqli_query  expects parameter 1 to be mysqli but is null`, I tried all suggestions are given on this page but none is working, all was working correctly and one day I started to coding again it started showing **error**, I tried all things please help me I thought may be it is problem with this code then for checking I write another code but that was also not working showing same error

**Here is my database code**

```
<?php
$db['host']='localhost';
$db['user_name']='root';
$db['password']='sudha';
$db['database']='cmss';
foreach($db as $key =>$value)
{
    define(strtoupper($key ), $value);
}
$con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
if($con)
{
    echo "running";
}

?>
```

Now here is mine code where it is showing error and all other pages but it is the sample only checking

```
<div class="widget">


         <div class="popular">
                                <?php
                                  $p_query="select * from post";  
                                  $p_run=mysqli_query($con,$p_query);
                                  if(mysqli_num_rows($p_run) > 0 )
                                   {
                                     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($p_run))
                                     {

                                     $id   = $row['id'];
                                     $date = getdate($row['date']);
                                     $title= $row['title'];
                                     $image=  $row['image'];
                                     $day  =  $date['mday'];
                                     $month=  $date['month'];
                                     $year =  $date['year'];
                                ?>
                             <hr>
                               <h4>Recent post</h4>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs4"><a href=""><img src="img/<?php echo $image;?>" alt="Post Picture"></a></div>
                                    <div class="col-xs8 detail">
                                        <h4><?php echo $title;?></h4>
                                        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $day-$month-$year; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <?php
                                     }}
                                         ?>
                              </div>
    </div><!-- widget close-->
    <div class="widget">
```

Comment: You include your db connection file ?

Comment: it is included sir

Comment: Is the code with the error inside a function? Does the function have `global $db;` so it can access the global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you are using the latest version of PHP and secondly, If your database connection code is in another file, make sure to include that file  in your main file.

If this also doesn't help, change your code to this :

```
function connect(){
    $db['host']='localhost';
    $db['user_name']='root';
    $db['password']='sudha';
    $db['database']='cmss';
    foreach($db as $key =>$value)
    {
        define(strtoupper($key ), $value);
    }
    $con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
    return $con;
}
```

And wherever you want to use this connection, simply create a variable and call connect() function through it like this:

```
$conn = connect();
```

Hope this works.

Comment: so in mysqli_query where  putting arguments  $con variable so you are saying that i would i have initialize $con = connect() before  and then send $ con in mysqli_query , please sir clear my confusion

Comment: thank you i sort out it by myself but thank you for suggesting

Comment: it is because of $con connection should be global so it should be call from anywhere .